# Rails query and order with same array used for query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have method

```
def self.get_ayahs_by_array(ayahs_keys_array)
  self.where(ayah_key: ayahs_keys_array)
end
```

Which does a query on the `Quran::Ayah` model. `ayahs_keys_array` is an array of keys (primary_key) in a certain order. The query returns a different order, but I want it to return as the same order as the queried array.

Example: `ayahs_keys_array` is `[5,4,1,2,7]` and I want it to return in THAT order and not `[1,2,4,5,7]`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to customize the order of a query.

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql:

```
self.where(ayah_key: ayahs_keys_array).order("FIELD(ayah_key, #{ ayahs_keys_array.joins(', ') })")
```

For postgres is slightly more complicated as you need to build whole CASE statement. Might be easier to do it on the application level:

```
self.where(ayah_key: ayahs_keys_array).order_by {|r| ayahs_keys_array.index r.ayah_key}
```

Finally, you can try this gem: https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified. If you do, please let us know how it went as I never used it.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this too `.sort{|e1, e2| ayahs_keys_array.index(e1.ayah_key) <=> ayahs_keys_array.index(e2.ayah_key)}` because `order_by` throws an error